# How do I Schedule timed events in python Flask?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, timer, scheduler

I'm working on a flask framework trying to schedule a job that will be triggered in 30 min from lunch and will happen only once.

I tried to work with *threading.Timer*,  But since my job calling a REST request I'm getting *RunTimeError: 'working outside of request context'*  which I just couldn’t solve.

From this thread, I understand that it is not recommended using the threading module on a flask server: 
[How do you schedule timed events in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268266/how-do-you-schedule-timed-events-in-flask/33268540#33268540)

So I'm looking for a solution for a timed trigger job (which doesn’t work on intervals).

It looks like APscheduler must be interval based.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Try to use `Celery`.

Comment: Hey,
I think my problem is maybe different, because spawning a new thread without a timer also leads to the same RunTimeError. 
It seems that when a new thread is created, it doesn't get an app context or a request context.
I managed to pass the app context as a parameter to the new thread; 
however, still there is no request context, and the exception the thrown when it tries to reach a request.  

Is it possible to generate a request, or should I pass it as well? 
Thanks :)

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/

Answer (score 3):

The apscheduler [add_job](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job) method can take a `date` trigger that will allow you to do what you want.

**Pro tips:**

If you use apscheduler inside your flask app process, when going into production with a wsgi server like gunicorn or uwsgi you will hand up with your job being run multiple time(one for each flask worker).

*When facing this issue the [gunicorn --preload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40162246/3775614) option didn't cut it for me.*

So:

- You can use flask-apscheduler with his rest server approach if that suits you.
- Or separate the apscheduler into a daemon and

  - use [uwsgi mules](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Mules.html),
  - or keep gunicorn running only the web app and use supervisor(or an equivalent) to start the scheduler daemon.

IMHO the separation of gunicorn/flask and apscheduler into two part and use of supervisor is the cleanest yet not so complex solution.

Comment: But separation of gunicorn and background job handled by supervisor is not an option in container.

Comment: @SerG you're right if we have one container with the all app, but best practice suggest to have one process per container, so I would put the wsgi flask app in one container, and the scheduler in another one.